# Images list doesn't display in flutter-web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a news app working fine on my phone, but when I try to launch it in a web browser, It shows errors instead of images. This problem occurs because browsers make sure that your web page doesn't display images from other pages. And I get those images from a NewsApi, which, as I understand, parses news sites.

I tried to follow through this guide: https://rodydavis.medium.com/displaying-html-in-flutter-8da44773764. But can't follow through. If incorporating the same code they give - it doesn't work. And I don't understand how to adjust it.
The error I get is:

> ======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
> The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
> Failed to load network image.
> Image URL: https://nextbigfuture.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2021/09/Screen-Shot-2021-09-11-at-4.31.43-PM-1024x646.jpg
> Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images. When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> Image provider: NetworkImage("https://nextbigfuture.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2021/09/Screen-Shot-2021-09-11-at-4.31.43-PM-1024x646.jpg", scale: 1)
> Image key: NetworkImage("https://nextbigfuture.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2021/09/Screen-Shot-2021-09-11-at-4.31.43-PM-1024x646.jpg", scale: 1)
> ====================================================================================================

I know that there is a URL to docs for solving this issue. But the instructions for that are too small. And more detailed solution is at article URL I provided above, with which I am not able to follow along.

The List Image View code is:

```
ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
        child: Image.network(
          article.urlToImage,
          key: UniqueKey(),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 200,
          loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
              ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
            if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
            return Center(
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 200,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                      ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                          loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                      : null,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

GitHub project URL: https://github.com/dimyak06112007/news_app/tree/updates.

[image: Screenshot of error and app in browser]

Comment: Have you tried Image.network(url) instead of NetworkImageProvieder?

Comment: I only tried Image.network(url). Should I try NetworkImageProvider too?

Comment: @DmytroYakymenko actually `Network.Image(...)` should work. Please edit your question with the code you tried for that and the exact errors you get from it. PS: Images are fine for showing results, but never for code; you should always put the code in formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

When you're loading images on the web there is a CORS factor that needs to be taken into account.

Browsers usually have some blocking rules for security when you load resources from 3rd party domains. There are multiple workarounds,

1. Using in-memory images
2. Hosting your images in a CORS-enabled CDN
3. Creating your own CORS proxy

Option 3 might suit your case because you're getting images from random places, you need to just mark them as CORS allowed.

More info on this link https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images#lack-control-over-the-image-server-use-a-cors-proxy